# Multiple background colors on div's background

Tags: css

Hey there I'm struggling with creating multiple colour background with CSS. I tried `gradient` but it makes shades which I doesn't want. I want to create this with CSS:

[image: Example of what I want to create with CSS]

Does anyone know how to create this without getting shades that I got when I used `gradient`.

Here is my html code.

```
<div id="head">
        <h1>Mira's place</h1><br>
        <h2><span id="quote">Mira is creating huge game named Rock Paper!</span></h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Games</li>
            <li>Applications</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: Does it have to be one div?

Comment: Just found this. I think it will help. http://patternizer.com/izfa

Comment: Well it doesn't really need to be one div. It just needs to be on one place. I will edit my question so you can see how my div looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know, what you mean with shades. Does the following not look like you wanted to? (Some modifications may be needed, but it shows the way to go)

```
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 25%,#0011ff 25%,#0011ff 35%,#ffffff 35%,#ffffff 65%,#ff0000 65%,#ff0000 75%,#ffffff 75%,#ffffff 100%);
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tg8AM/2/).

Answer (score 4):

Try it again with gradients, but with this code:

```
#head /* or body */
{
        -webkit-background-size: 40px 40px;
        -moz-background-size: 40px 40px;
        background-size: 40px 40px;         
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom,
                                color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05)), color-stop(.25, transparent),
                                color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05)),
                                color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05)), color-stop(.75, transparent),
                                to(transparent));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, transparent 25%,
                            transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%,
                            transparent 75%, transparent);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, transparent 25%,
                            transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%,
                            transparent 75%, transparent);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, transparent 25%,
                            transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%,
                            transparent 75%, transparent);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, transparent 25%,
                            transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%,
                            transparent 75%, transparent);
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, transparent 25%,
                            transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%,
                            transparent 75%, transparent);

         -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4);
         -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4);       
         box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4);
         width: 100%;
         border: 1px solid;
         color: #fff;
         padding: 15px;
         position: fixed;
         _position: absolute;
         text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

BTW: I got this code from www.red-team-design.com.  Here is the [link](http://www.red-team-design.com/cool-notification-messages-with-css3-jquery).

Answer (score 1):

```
.element{
    border-bottom: 25px solid #2C58DF;
    border-top: 25px solid #D71E26;
    height: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(165px) translateY(55px) rotate(135deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
    -moz-transform: translateX(165px) translateY(55px) rotate(135deg);
    transform: translateX(165px) translateY(55px) rotate(135deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/etW25/

Comment: This will rotate the contents too.

Comment: You can add this element as a child with position absolute to your div with content. Also, you should move it a little to crop edges (if parent div will have overflow:hidden;).